# How to reduce loading times in Forza Motorsport 4?

Tags: xbox-360, forza-motorsport-4

I have installed the game to my Xbox 360 hard drive, yet the loading times between races are still very slow.  Is there anything else I can do to speed the loading times up?

Comment: Given that it's a console, I'd guess your options would be limited. Sounds like they improved it some over Forza 3, but they are still fairly long load times that are affected by the track and number of cars.

Answer (score 1):

No. About the only way you would be able to speed things up would be to figure out how to hack your 360 to put in an SSD in place of the hard drive. Given the way the firmware on the hard drives is secure, that's currently impossible. Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: You could always format an external SSD disc for use with the XBox. Size limit is something like 8Gb, but that's more than enough for a Forza install.